# Easily get several materials from different objects onto 1 UV map/material?

Tags: unity, performance, blender, materials

Im trying to improve performance, and I found an asset called https://forum.unity.com/threads/one-batch-combine-hundreds-of-materials-into-one-draw-call.555643/ that claims to do what I need -  which is reducing many material maps across multiple objects to 1 material.

These are baked maps from blender, and Im using just a standard shader with albedo and emission really. OneBatch does not work, and I need to know within unity (or blender really) if theres a way to easily pack these maps into 1 file and/or material, without screwing up the existent UV unwrapping.

All the maps are the same size, and there are 1-3 per object (different sub meshes). What are some solutions?

Comment: Reading the link, it looks like OneBatch is using a custom texture format to improve static batching of multiple materials across multiple objects. Are you trying to have multiple objects use a single combined material?

Comment: Yes. Im trying to reduce draw calls. But (the creator did say it was beta), when I use OneBatch some of my meshes inevitably disappear.

Comment: Can you be more specific what your current material/mesh situation is, and maybe what level of experience you're coming from? Static batching & programmatic material-modification is kind of complex, and it's hard for me to figure out how to explain what you need without a better sense of where you're at. You can also try asking on that OneBatch thread, specifically, if you'd like to know if that tool does what you need it to do.